# Cuadro de color Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

alguien sabe por qué después de la linea 5603 visual code ya no muestra el selector de color

[image]

Comment: capaz por la mucha cantidad de líneas de código los cuadros de ayuda ya no se muestran, quizás también sea por el rendimiento del ordenador...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.